# Can I make readmemh warning fatal?

Tags: verilog

I have a generated data file that I'm reading into a memory.  Each test can generated a different data file to be read into memory.

If the generated data file is larger than the memory, I get these subtle hard to debug errors.  I'd like to catch these errors at readmemh time.

I see ncsim will give a warning:

> ncsim: *W,RMEMAR: $readmem warning: address incremented out of range.
>   Too many data words read  at line 16386 of file "happ.dat". Current
>   address: 16385, address range: [0:16384].

But as we all know, warnings are largely ignored.  How can I make this warning fatal?  Or is there another way to check if the .dat file is too big?

Answer (score 3):

Based on `Cadence® NC-Verilog® Simulator Help` you can use a `-ncfatal` option:

> -NCFatal {warning_code|error_code}
>
> Increase the severity level of the specified warning message or error message from warning
>   or error to fatal. The warning_code or error_code argument is the message code
>   (mnemonic) that appears in the message following the severity code. You can include multiple `-ncfatal` options on the command line.

Example:

```
% ncsim -ncfatal RMEMAR worklib.top:module
```

PS You can also use `-ncerror` option if you want to increase the severity level of the specified warning message from warning to error.